Calling HTTP API in Azure Data Factory Data Flows
I am new to Azure Data Factory. My requirement is to read data from Azure SQL server tables, perform few transformations and then call an external REST API.
I can add SQL database as a source but not able to configure REST API because Data Flows accepts only REST connector and due to API Accept header restriction (Azure REST only accepts application/json but the API expects different format in header due to versioning being included in the Accept header) and hence can't use this.
Can someone please guide how can I proceed usign ADF/Data Flows to call the API.

In this case you can try using SQL or Blob as temporary location as a workaround.
First use dataflow with your SQL table as source and perform your transformations in the dataflow. After dataflow, add a Blob file or another SQL temporary table as sink and copy the data to it.
After the dataflow activity, use a copy activity with the temporary data as source and a HTTP dataset to your API (give your API header here) as sink.

At the end of the pipeline run, all of your source SQL table data will be sent to the required API. But working of this approach might depend on the data size. If that's the case, instead of copy activity, it's better to use any code through function app to send the data from temporary location to your API. You can call that function app from ADF using function app activity after the dataflow activity.
